# Change the filenames of files named like "handNNN.jpg" with N being a digit (0-9), by adding a 0 before the NNN, with python

Tags: python

I have a directory, where I have filenames named like "handNNN.jpg", for example I have "hand386.jpg" and basically I want to add a 0 between "d" and "3" in this case, so in this example I want "hand0386.jpg". I want to do this in Visual Studio Code, with Python 3

```
import os

# Set the directory containing the files
directory = r"C:\Users\anton\Documents\Photos"

# Loop through all files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    # Check if the file is a handNNN.jpg file
    if filename.startswith("hand") and filename.endswith(".jpg") and filename[4:].isdigit():
        # Get the number in the filename
        number = int(filename[4:])
        # Add a 0 before the number
        new_number = "{:03d}".format(number)
        # Create the new filename
        new_filename = "hand" + new_number + ".jpg"
        # Rename the file
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory, filename), os.path.join(directory, new_filename))
```

I tried with this, but the filenames didn't change.

Comment: use a debugger, why not use `filename[:4]+'0'+filename[4:]`, `isdigit()` matches more characters that `[0-9]`, Better to use a regex to see if filename is a match

Comment: If `filename.endswith(".jpg")` then `filename[4:].isdigit()` won't be `True`, so the rest never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this here in the code in your for loop inside the if condition.

```
os.rename(os.path.join(directory, filename), os.path.join(directory, f"hand{int(filename[4:-4]):04d}.jpg"))
```

I am using the os library to check for the existing filename and rename the file and also i am using the **os** module to create path for the files using **os.join()**. This should work fine

Comment: The filenames didn't change :(